# Wordpress Display Name Stored In Two Places?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am wanting to work with the wordpress Display name, however I have realized that this seems to be stored in 2 places in the DB:

wp_users > display_name

wp_usermeta > meta_key (with the value of display_name)

If I do:

```
get_currentuserinfo();
echo $current_user->display_name;
```

or

```
get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' )
```

These both seem to be pulling from the wp_usermeta.

Questions:

1. Why is display name stored in two locations?
2. Where is the field in wp_users used in WP?
3. Is there a function to reference the one stored in wp_users (display and update)?
4. If I am updating the display name, should I be updating BOTH of these fields?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would look here:
[Wordpress Change Default Display Name Publicy As for all existing users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326315/wordpress-change-default-display-name-publicy-as-for-all-existing-users)

And here:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/change-default-display-name-1

Both links describe how to safely override the function.