# Wordpress Change Default Display Name Publicy As for all existing users

Tags: wordpress

does anyone know of way I can change the existing display name publicly as for all users. I want to have firstname lastname as the default because this will reflect in the forum. I have read all the forums and have tried all the hacks, any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Problem with using the admin_head hook is that it doesn't work for users who don't use the admin system. Also, my attempts to implement the solution posted by Marty failed because it doesn't seem that the display_name can be updated by update_user_meta() - you have to use wp_update_user().

My proposal - put this in your functions.php file:

```
function force_pretty_displaynames($user_login, $user) {

    $outcome = trim(get_user_meta($user->ID, 'first_name', true) . " " . get_user_meta($user->ID, 'last_name', true));
    if (!empty($outcome) && ($user->data->display_name!=$outcome)) {
        wp_update_user( array ('ID' => $user->ID, 'display_name' => $outcome));    
    }
}
add_action('wp_login','force_pretty_displaynames',10,2);
```

For me (using WP 3.4.1), that works OK, replacing the display name as soon as they log in.

Comment: Still Working on version 5.2.3

Answer (score 14):

Here's an improved version of **richplane's** answer that works in newer versions of WordPress (3.8+):

```
/**
* Format WordPress User's "Display Name" to Full Name on Login
* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

add_action( 'wp_login', 'wpse_9326315_format_user_display_name_on_login' );

function wpse_9326315_format_user_display_name_on_login( $username ) {
    $user = get_user_by( 'login', $username );

    $first_name = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'first_name', true );
    $last_name = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'last_name', true );

    $full_name = trim( $first_name . ' ' . $last_name );

    if ( ! empty( $full_name ) && ( $user->data->display_name != $full_name ) ) {
        $userdata = array(
            'ID' => $user->ID,
            'display_name' => $full_name,
        );

        wp_update_user( $userdata );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

A old question but my answer might be usefull for someone else.

Run this query on your database (adjust table names if you have another prefix):

`UPDATE wp_users SET display_name = CONCAT((SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'first_name' AND user_id = ID), ' ', (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'last_name' AND user_id = ID));`

On WP 3.3.1 but should work on later versions.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

//Sets the user's display name (always) to first name last name, when it's avail.
add_action ('admin_head','make_display_name_f_name_last_name');
function make_display_name_f_name_last_name(){

    $users = get_users(array('fields'=>'all'));

    foreach($users as $user){   
        $user = get_userdata($user->ID);    

        $display_name = $user->first_name . " " . $user->last_name;

        if($display_name!=' ') wp_update_user( array ('ID' => $user->ID, 'display_name' => $display_name) );
            else wp_update_user( array ('ID' => $user->ID, 'display_name' => $user->display_login) );

        if($user->display_name == '') 
            wp_update_user( array ('ID' => $user->ID, 'display_name' => $user->display_login) );
    }   
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks @aubreypwd this is what I needed. I've imported a whole lotta users via CSV and needed to change everyone's display_name to their first and last name. So I ran this function once in functions.php and voila, all done! :D Thanks again!!! For future users, I plan to use another script to force display_name as first & last name.

Comment: -1 Doing this for all users on admin_head is a really bad idea unless you plan on never having more than a few users.  I found this exact code in use on a site I just inherited.  Admin pages took almost 1 minute to load with under 2000 users.  Over 5 million PHP calls were eliminated when the above add_action was commented out.  Now admin page loads immediately.

Comment: This answer did exactly what I was needing, thank you! The admin part of the site did tremendously slow down since we had so many users. I ended up running this function once, which changed all of our display names, and then moved the function to only run when a new user is created. Now all of the users have the correct display names and new users will as well, and the site stays speedy!

Answer (score 0):

**use this code in function.php** 
this code juste for change display_name and replace with first_name plus first letter for last_name in step the new user or update info for user .

```html
//Change the publicly displayed name on comments
 add_filter('pre_user_display_name','default_display_name');
  function default_display_name($name) {
    global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();
   
   $lastname=mb_substr($current_user->user_lastname, 0, 1, "UTF-8");
   $name =  ucfirst($current_user->user_firstname) .' '.ucfirst($lastname). '.';
   return $name;
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

Quick and dirty hack would be to edit the file 'wp-includes/user.php' edit the folowing

```
if ( empty($display_name) )
    $display_name = $user_login;
    $display_name = apply_filters('pre_user_display_name', $display_name);
```

Edit this line

```
$display_name = $user_login;
```

Change to:

```
$display_name = $first_name . ' ' . $last_name;
```

The above solution should work, assuming that the user.php file isn't changed in a WordPress update or alternativly you could add something like this to your functions.php

```
//force display-name of users to Firstname Lastname
add_action('admin_head','force_pretty_displaynames');
function force_pretty_displaynames() {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ($current_user->display_name != $current_user->first_name." ".$current_user->last_name){ 
       update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'display_name', $current_user->first_name." ".$current_user->last_name);
    }

}
```

but agian a few checks on this above could be added to see if the user is logged in, is an admin, contributor etc..etc..

but should do what your looking for..

Source: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/change-default-display-name-1

Marty

Comment: acutally I was able to do it with the following code:     $user_id = $current_user->ID;
    $loginfullname = $current_user->user_firstname.'&nbsp;'.$current_user->user_lastname;
    wp_update_user( array ('ID' => $user_id, 'display_name' => $loginfullname) );

Comment: Never ever edit core or plugin files. Use hooks (or overrides) like in Marty's second suggestion.